# multithreading program to perform word count frequency- Segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, mutex

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;

//typedef struct for a word
typedef struct {
    char word[101];
    int frequency;
}Word;

//struct for thread
struct ft{
    char* fileName;
    int start;
    int stop;
};

//compare frequency of 2 words 
int compareWords(const void *f1, const void *f2){
    Word *a = (Word *)f1;
    Word *b = (Word *)f2;
    return (b->frequency - a->frequency);
}

//count frequency of a word
void countFrequency(void *arg){

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    int i, c;
    struct ft* fi = (struct ft*)arg;
    FILE *file = fopen(fi->fileName,"r");
    fseek(file,fi->start,SEEK_SET);
    for(i = 0; i < fi->stop - fi->start; i++){
        c = getc(file);
        //printf("%d\n", c);
        //frequency count
    }

    fclose(file);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){

    //variabies for <time.h>
    struct timespec startTime;
    struct timespec endTime;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &startTime);

    /*------------main------------------*/

    //variables
    int nthreads;   //number of threads
    int chunkSize;  //each threas processing size

    //if user input is not correct, inform
    if(argc < 3){ 
       printf("./a.out text_file #ofthreads \n");
       exit(-1);
    }


    nthreads = atoi(argv[2]);
    chunkSize = sizeof(argv[1])/nthreads;

    //declare threads and default attributes
    pthread_t threads[nthreads];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    //run threads in parallel
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
       struct ft data[nthreads];
       data[i].start = i*chunkSize;
       data[i].stop = data[i].start+chunkSize;
       data[i].fileName = argv[1];


       // Create a new thread for every segment, and count word  frequency for each
       pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, (void*) countFrequency, (void*) &data[i]);

    }

    //wait for results (all threads)
    for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
       pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    } 

       //func of <time.h>
       clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &endTime);
       time_t sec = endTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec;
       long n_sec = endTime.tv_nsec - startTime.tv_nsec;
       if (endTime.tv_nsec < startTime.tv_nsec)
        {
        --sec;
        n_sec = n_sec + 1000000000L;
        }
       printf("Total Time was %ld.%09ld seconds\n", sec, n_sec);
}
```

I'm working on this program to use multiple threads to read and process a large text file and perform a word count frequency of the top 10 most frequent words in the text that are longer than 6 characters long. But I keep getting the segmentation fault error im not sure why, does anybody have any idea.?

Comment: Try to move out this line from the for loop `struct ft data[nthreads];`

Comment: What is your intent with this line? `chunkSize = sizeof(argv[1])/nthreads;`. Seems strange for me. And what arguments you use to call this program?

Comment: @Eraklon the arguments would be the filename of the textfile im reading and "nthreads" is the second argument i input at the command line to tell the program how many threads i want to be reading the text file

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
   for (i = 0; i < nthreads; i++){
       struct ft data[nthreads];
```

declares `data` that is live (legal to use) for the duration of this for loop. This code:

```
      pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, (void*) countFrequency, (void*) &data[i]);
   }
```

passes the address of `data` into the threads, and then exits the loop. Once the loop is done, `data` is no longer live, and all access to it leads to undefined behavior.

The compiler is free to write anything else to the memory where `data` used to be.

The immediate cause of the crash is that if one of the threads doesn't execute `fopen` *before* `data` is overwritten, then `fopen` may fail, and you don't check for the failure in `fopen`.

P.S.

As Eraklon noted, this code: `chunkSize = sizeof(argv[1])/nthreads;` will divide `sizeof(char*)` (either 4 or 8 depending on whether you build for 32-bit or for 64-bit) by number of threads. That is unlikely to be what you want, and will yield `chinkSize==0` for `nthreads > 4` on 32-bit and `nthreads > 8` on 64-bit machines.

P.P.S.

There is a concurrency bug in your program as well: since each of the `countFrequency` invocations locks the same `lock` *for the entire duration*, they will all run in sequence (one after another), never in parallel. Thus your program will be slower than if you just did all the work in your main thread.